# Avoid the removal of "https:" from URLs

Tags: urls, https, site-url

WordPress is changing all my URLs from:

```
https://www.example.com/...
```

to:

```
//www.example.com/...
```

For example:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="//www.example.com/"/>
```

I don't want this to happen, because it has some side effects with CDN rewriting, and my site is https only.

What is the best way to disable this "feature"?

Comment: To me this sounds like a bug in some plugin. Try to disable all plugins and/or change the theme and see if that behavior is gone. Then re-activate plugin after plugin and check when the behavior is back…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by CloudFlare https (which doesn't set the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` variable), I solved it by forcing:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

in the webserver configuration. After doing so I could also disable the [CloudFlare Flexible SSL plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/), and get a little performance gain.

Comment: Since you were able to answer your own question, please click the green checkmark to indicate that this is resolved for record's sake. Thanks